# The closed unit adic disk

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, rigid-analytic-geometry, perfectoid-spaces

I am reading the Scholze-Weinstein Berkeley lecture notes on "Perfectoid Spaces", and in particular I am stuck trying to understand the closed adic unit disk, which is the second example of an adic space given in Chapter 4.

SW say that the closed adic unit disk is the functor $\mathcal{D}: \text{adic spaces}\longrightarrow \text{Sets}$, sending an adic space $X$ to $\mathcal{O}^+(X)$, the global sections of its "sheaf of integers".

SW say that the functor $\mathcal{D}$ is representable by the adic space $\text{Spa}(\mathbb{Z}[T],\mathbb{Z}[T])$, written as $\text{Spa}\mathbb{Z}[T]$ in short. SW then say that if $K$ is a nonarchimedean field, and $\text{Spa}(K,\mathcal{O}_K)$ is the associated adic space denoted $\text{Spa}K$ in short, then $\mathcal{D}(\text{Spa}K) \cong \text{Spa}\mathbb{Z}[T]\times \text{Spa}K \cong \text{Spa}(K\langle T\rangle,\mathcal{O}_K\langle T\rangle)$.

SW doesn't say it explicitly, but I assume that this notation denotes a fibred product over the final object in the category of adic spaces, $\text{Spa}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$. There are two things which I do not understand.

1. Why is $\mathcal{D}(\text{Spa}K) \cong \text{Spa}\mathbb{Z}[T]\times \text{Spa}K$ true? I mean, by definition, $\mathcal{D}(\text{Spa}K)\cong \mathcal{O}^+(\text{Spa}K)\cong \mathcal{O}_K$.
2. Why is the product of $\text{Spa}\mathbb{Z}[T]$ and $\text{Spa}K$ in the category of adic spaces isomorphic to $\text{Spa}(K\langle T\rangle,\mathcal{O}_K\langle T\rangle)$? This is the same as saying that the coproduct of $(\mathbb{Z}[T], \mathbb{Z}[T])$ and $(K,\mathcal{O}_K)$ in the category of adic pairs is $(K\langle T\rangle, \mathcal{O}_K\langle T\rangle)$, but I think that their coproduct should be $(K[T], \mathcal{O}_K[T])$.

Comment: What topology do you endow $K[T]$ and $\mathcal O_K[T]$?

Comment: I understand you are trying to insinuate that I am taking the topology induced from the Gauss norm, but actually, in hindsight, I am not even sure I understand how to define a topology on the tensor product of topological rings.